# why I can't get all documents stored in firestore sub collection?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have users collection that has sub collection called attendedEvents like the picture below. as you can see there are 3 documents in the attendedEvents sub collection

[image]

I try to get all documents available on that sub collection by using the code below, I just want to get it all, without order, limit or anything using `getDocuments`

```
    func getAttendedEventsFromBeginning(completion: @escaping (_ eventID: [String]?,QueryDocumentSnapshot?)->Void) {

        FirestoreDocumentReference.users(uidUser: uid).reference().collection("attendedEvents")
            .getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in

                let lastDocument = snapshot?.documents.last

                if let error = error {
                    completion(nil,lastDocument)
                    print("Error when fetching attended events documents in user subcollection: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                } else {
                    print("Successfully fetching attended events documents in user subcollection from Firestore ")

                    guard let documentsSnapshot = snapshot else {
                        completion(nil,lastDocument)
                        return
                    }

                    let eventDocuments = documentsSnapshot.documents
                    print("xxxxx")
                    print(eventDocuments)

                    var attendedeventIDs = [String]()

                    for document in eventDocuments {
                        let eventDictionary = document.data()
                        let theEvent = eventDictionary["eventID"] as! String
                        attendedeventIDs.append(theEvent)
                    }

                    print(attendedeventIDs)

                    completion(attendedeventIDs,lastDocument)
                }
            }
    }
```

but as a result, I just got 2 document snapshot, it should be 3 documents
[image]

but if I delete the app from simulator and install it again, I got all the three data. is is cached or what?

Answer (score 3):

I have been in the same situation. In my case, this happens because in my document it only contains subcollection. And that will cause the document itself to not be shown in queries or snapshots.
My walkaround method is to add some random info in the document to make it exist.